# Detect when app resigns active in cocoa?

Tags: cocoa

Is there any way to detect when an app is no longer active? That is, listen for changes to this:

```
[NSApp isActive]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your app delegate, implement your choice of `-applicationDidResignActive:` or `-applicationWillResignActive:`.

Alternately, listen for the `NSApplicationDidResignActiveNotification` or  `NSApplicationWillResignActiveNotification` notifications on NSApp.

Comment: Ah, so there is a notification. Must have missed that in the documentation. Thanks Jim!